# Uncompress an tar.bz2 file with Python tarfile module

Tags: python, tarfile

I have many files with the extension "tar.bz2" and I want to uncompress them.
So I use the "tarfile" module as explained here : *https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html.*

I try the following code :

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open("path_to/test/sample.tar.bz2", "r:bz2")  
for i in tar:
  tar.extractall(i)
tar.close()
```

But nothing happens : the tar.bz2 file has not been uncompressed into the folder "path_to/test/".

Would you have any ideas ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You use tar.extractall with wrong argument. I think, you need something like this

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open("path_to/test/sample.tar.bz2", "r:bz2")  
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
```

or

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open("path_to/test/sample.tar.bz2", "r:bz2")  
for i in tar:
  tar.extractfile(i)
tar.close()
```

If you need to extract files to some specific folder

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open("path_to/test/sample.tar.bz2", "r:bz2")  
tar.extractall(some_path)
tar.close()
```

Comment: Thank you. But I tried both of your solutions but same result : nothing happens..

Answer (score 5):

I like the context manager:

```
import tarfile

def extract_bz2(filename, path="."):
    with tarfile.open(filename, "r:bz2") as tar:
        tar.extractall(path)
```