# How to *properly* compress and decompress a text file using bz2 and python

Tags: python, compression, tar, bz2

So I've had this system that scrapes and compresses files for a while now using bz2 compression. The way it does so is using the following block of code I found on SO a few months back:

Let's assume for the purposes of this post the filename is always `file.XXXX` where `XXXX` is the relevant extension. We start with `.txt`

```
### How to compress a text file
filepath_compressed = "file.tar.bz2"
with open("file.txt", 'rb') as data:
    tarbz2contents = bz2.compress(data.read(), 9)
    with bz2.BZ2File(filepath_compressed, 'wb') as f_comp:
        f_comp.write(tarbz2contents)
```

Now, to decompress it, I've always got it to work using a decompression software I have called Keka which decompresses the `.tar.bz2` file to `.tar`, then I run it through Keka again to get an "extensionless" file which I then add a `.txt` to on my mac and then it works.

Now, to do decompress programmatically, I've tried a few things. I've tried the stuff from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416001/uncompress-an-tar-bz2-file-with-python-tarfile-module) and the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073295/possible-to-decompress-bz2-in-python-to-a-file-instead-of-memory). I've tried using BZ2Decompressor and BZ2File and everything. I just seem to be missing something and I'm not sure what it is.

Here is what I have so far, and I'd like to know what is wrong with this code:

```
import bz2, tarfile, shutil

# Decompress to tar
with bz2.BZ2File("file.tar.bz2") as fr, open("file.tar", "wb") as fw:
    shutil.copyfileobj(fr, fw)
    
# Decompress from tar to txt
with tarfile.open("file.tar", "r:") as tar:
    tar.extractall("file_out.txt")
```

This code crashes because of a "`tarfile.ReadError: truncated header`" problem. I think the first context manager outputs a binary text file, and I tried decoding that but that failed too. What am i missing here i feel like a noob.

---

If you would like a minimum runnable piece of code to replicate this, add the following to make a dummy file:

```
lines = ["Line 1","Line 2", "Line 3"]

with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line+"\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing that you're making is not a `.tar.bz2` file, but rather a `.bz2.bz2` file. You are compressing *twice* with bzip2 (the second time with no effect), and there is no tar file generation anywhere to be seen.